# Is increasing the message queue depth is an appropriate solution to sync Producer and Consumer in C/Linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, message-queue

This is more sounds like a design issue to me.

Scenario -

I have an embedded system with multiple threads -
One of the thread is xxx -- a networking protocol that tells the neighbour router  -- Producer

Another thread is xxx-TE - this a traffic engineering - xxx protocol.  - Consumer.

They both are communicating to each other via. Message queue. So, basically the producer puts the data in the xxx-TE queue for the thread xxx-TE.

Problem -

When we have a lot of nodes or in simple words a lot of routing information from xxx, the message put in the xxx - TE queue is lost.

Solution -

Is this the solution correct?
Should we increase the queue-depth so that the message is not lost.

[symptoms] - We see errors while pushing the message in the message queue.

Comment: strongly suggest implementing the message queue so the producer 'hangs' when the the message queue is full and continues when the message queue again has room for the new message. If the consumer cannot keep up with the message rate, perhaps it will be necessary to have more than one consumer thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not.

Generally speaking, message queues should stay empty, or close to empty, as much of the time as possible. If your queue is not usually empty, you need to improve the speed at which messages are being processed.

Increasing the size of the queue is generally not a solution; if the queue is being filled faster than it is being emptied, it will *always* end up full in the end; increasing the size will only make it take slightly longer to fill up.

(An exception is if messages are being produced in an extremely "bursty" pattern. If this is the case, increasing the queue size may help to buffer against those bursts. However, a large burst, or several bursts back to back, may put you back in the same situation.)